# Open Linux FIFO file as non blocking mode using FileStream

Tags: c#, linux, debian, .net-core, named-pipes

Is it possible to open Linux FIFO as non blocking using `FileStream`?
Also want to expect to be able to close it by user code, even if write-side is not opened.

This code keeps waiting till write-side opened although use `FileOptions.Asynchronous`.
It is on top of `.NET Core 2.0` and Debian jessie / macOS.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadFifo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fifoPath = "/tmp/fifofile";
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fifoPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write, 4096,
                FileOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FileStream opened.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> [CoreFX implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs)
>   - GitHub
>   [CoreFX test](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/221950b31c1057b040670936519ddbc13f893062/src/System.IO.FileSystem/tests/FileStream/Pipes.cs#L45) - GitHub
>   [Debian FIFO(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/fifo.7.en.html) 
>   - Manpages

Comment: have you resolved this? I am struggling with the same problem in dotnet core 3.1

Comment: @Przemo Unfortunately, no progress. Hope expect support from msft or dotnet core team...

Comment: There is a read timeout property but for now no luck with making it work with filestream. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readtimeout?view=netcore-3.1